# Build input file cannot be found Xcode 14 iOS 15.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build an Xcode project on a real device and getting the error below. The build works on the Simulator but not on the device.

*error build: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tripper-fofjrpvuxfttvyhkkbmgtzkzglpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Tripper.app/Tripper'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?*

Tried every solution I could find on StackOverflow and elsewhere but nothing works.

Answer (score 7):

under project.pbxproj
there was
EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64 ;
**which I removed, then started working**

Comment: removing EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64; for Release works for me. But I had to keep EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64; for Debug in order to run the app on the simulator.

Comment: yes this works for release, while for debug, we need to keep

Answer (score 1):

In Build Settings under Excluded Architectures, make sure you're not listing arm64. Do you have anything listed there?